# Gradle error after update: com.android.tools:sdk-common

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

I updated Android Studio to the last version (3.1 Canary 8) and mandatorily the com.android.tools.build:gradle to version 3.1.0-alpha08, but syncing the project I get this error:

```
Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.0-alpha08).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.0-alpha08/sdk-common-26.1.0-alpha08.jar
```

I searched around but not solution found, can someone help me solve this issue?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha07'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE: this is the new bukd.gradle (project):**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha08'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: For the sake of the knowledge ;) I fixed it by adding google() above jcenter() in the repositories block as suggested by the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the sake of the knowledge ;) I fixed it by adding google() above jcenter() in the repositories block as suggested by the official documentation: [developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html](http://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

Answer (score 15):

Please go to project gradle file and add google() above jcenter().

[image]

Comment: This answer is completely equal to mine ;)