# Failed to resolve: firebase-iid-interop

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

[This is Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVlYS.png)

[image]

I've facing this problem can anyone help me? I search everywhere, but I can't find the solution

```
Failed to resolve: firebase-common Open File
Failed to resolve: firebase-iid-interop Open File
Failed to resolve: firebase-measurement-connector Open File
```

And Im Using 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`
my Gradle File :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.*****"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 27
      versionCode 20
      versionName "2.0"

      multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
}

// Maven Repositories
repositories {

  google()
  mavenCentral()
  flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
  maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
  maven { url "https://bitbucket.org/adscend/androidsdk/raw/master/" }
  maven { name "Fyber's maven repo"
        url "https://fyber.bintray.com/maven" }

}

dependencies {

  // test Libraries
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

  // Android Support Libraries
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'

  // Adnetwork Libraries
  implementation 'com.fyber:fyber-sdk:8.19.0'
  implementation(name: 'adgatemediasdk', ext: 'aar')
  implementation(name: 'OfferToroSdk-v3.1.10', ext: 'aar')
  implementation 'com.adscendmedia.sdk:adscendmedia:2.3.4'
  implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.4@jar'

  // MultiDex Dependency
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

  // Other Libraries
  implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
  implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
  implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
  implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
  implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
  implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
  implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'

  // Facebook Login only
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.34.0'

  // slider library
  implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

  // Google Libraries
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'

  // Firebase
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks you .

Comment: Try to sync again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Comment Alex Mamo  i Try Many time But it's not Work but now i find the solution. for Bob Snyder Answer 
Thank you again for your comment :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of the [June 12th release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_12_2018) of the Firebase SDK, you must explicitly include `firebase-core`:

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list
>   `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase
>   services to work as expected.

Add:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Bob Snyder For Your Aswer. when i add 
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` it's not solve but when i Clean The Project 
i HAve A New Error `Could not find firebase-common.aar` 
then i find the solution here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242111/gradle-error-after-update-com-android-toolssdk-common 

And It's Working Now!!!! Thank you so much for your Help :)

Comment: If you are still having the problem like me, make sure you use the latest:
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'`. `16.0.1` still gives the error.

Answer (score 50):

You need to put google() repository **BEFORE** jcenter().

This is because Google removed their projects from jcenter, but erroneously left some artifacts with dependencies.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! I very reluctantly gave this a try... But it WORKED! thanks @Borzh

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Amazing !! Thank you

Comment: Excellent!!  work

Comment: What the heck!!! It worked....And I don't have any clue why

Comment: WTH, It works....big thumbs up

Answer (score 6):

Update the dependencies version to the latest one.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As @Borzh suggested, adding google() repository before jcenter() repo worked for me. Please note this change has to be done at both "project level gradle file "(top level build file) and module level build file.

> ### Project level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

> ### Module level build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```